# Is it possible to add padding within a figure?

Tags: floats, fancybox

In my document, I have this code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \Ovalbox{\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{sym_transistors}}
  \caption{}
  \label{sym:transistors}
\end{figure}
```

It yields this output:

[image]

As you can see in the bottom right corner, the Ovalbox is very tight. The simple solution for this is to open the eps-file in Inkscape and add an invisible rectangle - bigger than the graphics - behind all the symbols and recompile the document.

But, instead of doing that, is it possible to increase the padding within the Ovalbox/figure so I don't have to edit the image? For example, CSS has the possibility to add "padding: 5px;" to an element, which will add a 5 pixel margin on all sides of the element. Is something similiar possible to do in LaTeX?

Comment: Is this the `\Ovalbox` from the `fancybox` package?

Comment: `\Ovalbox{ \includegraphics{} }`  would have padding either side compared to `\Ovalbox{\includegraphics{}}`

Comment: Anyways, if `fancybox`, the padding is determined by the length `\fboxsep`, as described in the manual. Add `\setlength\fboxsep{20pt}` (or some other suitable length).